# iPhone doesn't play HD video through UIWebView, when iPad does

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, html5-video

I try to play video with this code:

```
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 160);

    NSString *embedHTML = @"<html><head>\
                            <body>\
                            <video src=\"http://cs13006.userapi.com/u57385256/video/c27ebefdeb.360.mp4\" controls</video>\
                            </body></html>";

    UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    [videoView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:videoView];
```

It works like charm, but if I change src to

http://cs13006.userapi.com/u57385256/video/c27ebefdeb.480.mp4 (480p)

or

http://cs13006.userapi.com/u57385256/video/c27ebefdeb.720.mp4 (720p)

It stops working on iPhone, but still working on iPad.

Or may it be only Simulator bug, and it will work on device? (I have no iPhone to test it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fixed in newer versions iOS.
Now this code works ok.